# Unitaries bringing a matrix to a diagonal matrix

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A_0$ be the set of all bounded operators over $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ which can be represented by (infinite) matrices satisfying
$$ \exists\ r \in \mathbb{N} \ \text{ s.t. }  a_{i,j}= 0 \ \text{ whenever } |i- j|> r $$

Setting $A= \overline{A_0}$ we can check that $A$ is a C*-algebra.

Consider the closed subspace ( even the C*-subalgebra ) $C= \{a\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb{N})) : a_{ij} = 0 \ \text{for } i\neq j\}$ 
and for $a= (a_{ij})_{i,j\in \mathbb{N}}\in A$ , define
$$E(a) :=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & 0 & 0 & \cdots  \\
    0 & a_{22} & 0 & \cdots  \\
    0 & 0 & a_{33} & \cdots  \\
    \vdots & \vdots &  & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix} \in C . $$
$E$ is actually a continuous projection $E^2= E:A\to C$ . 
We can check that for all $a \in A$ and all unitaries  $u\in C:\  E(u^*au) = E(a)$ .

For a fixed $a\in A$ let $S= \big\{s=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^ku_i^*au_i\ \big|\ k\in \mathbb{N},\ u_1,\dots,u_k\in C \text{ are unitaries}\big\}$ 
the set of all finite averages of that form.

$\textbf{Show that }$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $\big\|s- E(s)\big\|< \epsilon $ 
or equivalently that $\big\|s- E(a)\big\|< \epsilon \ $ from the earlier remark $E(u^*au) = E(a)$

I am just looking for a hint if possible. 
Writing down explicitly the terms doesn't help, so I am supposing we should use some sort of property of the projection $E$ ( but $A$ is not a Hilbert space itself ) and/or structure of unitaries 
( the conjugacy action $a\mapsto u^*au$ being a *-automorphism $A\to A$ ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question!

**Hint:** what you want is to get all non-diagonal entries of $S$ to be small. More concretely, write the expression for $s_{kj}$ and think $n^{\rm th}$-roots of unity for your unitaries. You should be able to get
$$
s-E(s)=\frac1n\,(a-E(a)). 
$$

Comment: How would you justify using the supremum norm like in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ ?
Here is what I considered: it suffices to bound each term $\Big|\sum\limits_j \Big(s- E(a)\Big)_{nj}\ x_j\Big|$ above by $\epsilon |x_n|$ for an arbitrary sequence $(x_n)$. That term is $\Big|\sum\limits_{j, j\neq n} \Big(\frac{a_{nj}}{k}\sum_{l=1}^k e^{\iota(\theta_j^l- \theta_n^l)}\Big)\ x_j\Big|$

Comment: what is $n$ in your answer? is it the $k$ ? The problem is that we want some sort of cancelling out with all the complex numbers in the unit circle, we need them to be $0$ as we can't determine what are the neighbouring values of $x_n$, i.e. $x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, \dots$

Comment: The $n$ is the $k$. It is not clear to me that  you can control the norm just from the computations. But controlling the norm of $\frac1n\,(a-E(a))$ is trivial.

Comment: Great! $k-1^{th}$ roots ! Thank you.